# How to move a View from one ViewGroup to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `LinearLayout1`, `LinearLayout2` and a `Button` in `MainActivity`. When I click the `Button`, I want it to jump from `LinearLayout1` to `LinearLayout2`. How can I do that?

Comment: Check out the `removeView()` and `addView()` methods of `ViewGroup`, of which a `LinearLayout` is a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_1);
LinearLayout mLinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_1);  
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
         mLinearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
         mLinearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of the many different views (not LinearLayouts) to be displayed right on the main activity (may depend on a condition or a state engine or time based interval), you probably can use **ViewFlipper**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you specially Mike M
i get my answer with:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

   final LinearLayout mLinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liner1);
    final LinearLayout mLinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liner2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mLinearLayout1.removeView(button);
            mLinearLayout2.addView(button);


                }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can hide and show one or the other, for example:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_1);
LinearLayout mLinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_1);

mLinearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mLinearLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But If you want to show an hide some views with diifferent behavior I recommend you using Fragments.

Comment: What if I have other elements in that layout? I want it happen just for that specific button